Preserve separately selectable Columns in PDF export of Excel document
When exporting Word documents or rendering LaTeX, you can designate columns and thus enable seperate selection of sections of the Document:

Meanwhile when exporting Excel, I could not find any way to designate Columns to achieve a similar effect with columns of Data:



Desired Behavior
Actual Behavior









Is there any way to properly designate the columns in this way? I do not mind having to use an external tool to achieve this if necessary, though compatibility with automation through either VBA or Python would be appreciated.
Note: If the Solution ends up selecting both columns in each subtable line-by-line without selecting the contents of the other subtables, that would also be acceptable.
I have already tried finding such a tool inside of Excel without success and googling the problem returns no relevant results.
